# iPad/iOS timing problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-audio

Recently someone contacted me about an iPad metronome that had some fairly subtle problems with timing. I've worked with a number of OS X applications that did not have problems with timing- they were very accurate.

The group he had do it are oriented towards UI stuff, I'm not sure if they know about how to set timing on iOS. I will get the source code from them, but I just want to make sure- does iPad/iOS have timing problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately CADisplayLink can be given only integer values and not floating point values. That means it is not going to work. I need to see if the customer would like me to go ahead with high precision timers to see if they work.

Answer (score 1):

The accuracy of the timer is based on which method you're employing. If they're using NSTimer it won't be terribly accurate as described in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html):

> Because of the various input sources a typical run loop manages, the
>   effective resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to on
>   the order of 50-100 milliseconds. ... Therefore, the actual time at
>   which the timer fires potentially can be a significant period of time
>   after the scheduled firing time.

However, [CADisplayLink](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/) paired with block callbacks is an **incredibly** accurate method of timing. Check to see which one they're using and refactor to `CADisplayLink` if they're using `NSTimer`.

Semi-Sudo code example (ripped from a personal project):

```
- (CADisplayLink*)displayLink{
    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(timerFired:)];
    _displayLink.frameInterval = 1;// 1 = Fire every time the frame updates
    [_displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)timerFired:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {

    for (TTRunLoopCallbackRegistrant *registrant in _timerRegistrants) {

        if (registrant.target && registrant.callback) {
            registrant.callback();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, I'll see what they are using for a timer.